# Having trouble with validating via grep

Tags: shell

```
list="feature test release"
branch=feature/fix
```

I am trying to check, if the branch name does not start with any prefix in the list, then exit the command. if the branch has one of prefix from the list, then is valid.

```
 echo $list| grep -e "$branch/[a-zA-Z0-9]" ; echo $?
```

unfortunately this command does not work too. Any idea?
i.e `test/bla` is valid branch name but `testtest/bla` not

Edit:
I am using `sh`, and the list of valid prefixes can be a single string or array, both is usable.

Comment: What shell do you want to use? `sh`? `bash`?  Is it a requirement to put the valid prefixes into a single string variable or could you use an array? Please [edit] your question to provide this information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: edited @Bodo, thanks for response

Comment: I tried to make your edit clear without my question. POSIX `sh` does not support arrays. I will write an answer using a HEREDOC.

Comment: sed and grep has blown my mind, I could not fix still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require to have the valid prefixes in a variable you can use any of the following solutions.

Depending on whether e.g. `feature/foo/bar` should be valid or not you have to remove only the last `/*` or all.

You may need a separate test to check if `branch` contains a `/` at all.

Example `check.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# foo/bar --> ^foo$
# foo --> ^foo$
# foo/bar/baz --> ^foo$
pattern='^'"${branch%%/*}"'$'

# search for pattern in input, suppress output
grep "$pattern" >/dev/null <<EOF
feature
test
release
EOF

echo $?
```

testing

```
$ branch=featur/fix ./check.sh
0
$ branch=foo/fix ./check.sh
1
$ branch=xfeature/fix ./check.sh
1
$ branch=featurex/fix ./check.sh
1
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)' comment, the above solution can produce unexpected matches if the supplied branch name contains any regex meta-characters, e.g. for `branch='.*'`.

Depending on the exact values to check, this can be avoided by enclosing the strings in delimiting characters, e.g. `/`.

```
# ...
pattern="/${branch%%/*}/"
# ...
fgrep "$pattern" >/dev/null <<EOF
/feature/
/test/
/release/
EOF
# ...
```

---

Example `check2.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# removes longest match /*
# foo/bar/baz --> foo
case "${branch%%/*}" in
feature|test|release)
    echo valid 1
    ;;
*)
    echo invalid 1
    ;;
esac

# removes shortedt match /*
# foo/bar/baz --> foo/bar
case "${branch%/*}" in
feature|test|release)
    echo valid 2
    ;;
*)
    echo invalid 2
    ;;
esac
```

testing

```
$ branch=feature/fix ./check2.sh
valid 1
valid 2
$ branch=feature/fix/bla ./check2.sh
valid 1
invalid 2
$ branch=xfeature/fix ./check2.sh
invalid 1
invalid 2
$ branch=featurex/fix ./check2.sh
invalid 1
invalid 2
```

Comment: Yeah, I have to modify but the essential part is your approach! appreciate it

Comment: Your `check.sh` says `.*` is a valid branch for instance.

Comment: @pulp_fiction The solution is based on the information available in your question. If you would have written more details about your use case I could have adapted my proposed solutions to these unknown requirements.

Comment: I don't mean it, I guess a generic solution is better for others as well. I will my modified solution down below

Answer (score 1):

If `$list` is meant to be a scalar variable containing a space-separated list of words and you want to check that `$branch` is one of those words followed by `/` followed by one or more ASCII alnums, in POSIX `sh`, you could do:

```
validate() (export LC_ALL=C
  list=$1 branch=$2
  case $branch in
    (*' '*) return 1;;
  esac
  case ${branch##*/} in
    ("" | *[![:alnum:]]*) return 1;;
  esac
  case " $list " in
    (*" ${branch%/*} "*) return 0;;
    (*) return 1;;
  esac
)
```

And then:

```
if validate "$list" "$branch"; then
  echo OK
else
  echo KO
fi
```

To do regexp matching of arbitrary strings (as opposed to lines), POSIXly, the main options are `expr` and it's `:` operator, though it uses basic regexps and has a few design issues and `awk` and its `~` operator (which uses extended regexps).

Here, you could do (assuming none of the words in `$list` are regexp operators):

```
validate() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -- '
    BEGIN {
      regexp = ARGV[1]
      branch = ARGV[2]
      gsub(" ", "|", regexp)
      regexp = "^("regexp")/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
      exit !(branch ~ regexp)
    }' "$@"
}
```

(here using `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `[[:alnum:]]` as you still come across `awk` implementations that don't support POSIX character classes).

A few things to bear in mind:

- `grep` works line-based, so you can't use it to validate arbitrary strings unless you've made sure those strings don't contain newline characters.
- In POSIX shells, parameter expansions must be quoted, or  otherwise they're subject to split+glob (no `echo $list`)
- `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data, use `printf` instead (so `echo $list` should be `printf '%s\n' "$list"`).
- Ranges like `0-9A-Za-z` can only be used in the C locale. In the C locale, `[0-9A-Za-z]` happens to match the same thing as `[[:alnum:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this,

```
list="feature test release"
branch=feature/fix
echo $list| grep -e "$branch/[a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

(and assuming an unmodified `$IFS` as you forgot to quote `$list`), you are effectively writing this:

```
echo feature test release | grep -e 'feature/fix/[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

and this is looking for the pattern `feature/fix/X` (for any alphanumeric character as `X`) in the string `feature test release`. That won't work.

You could change the format of list to become a Regular Expression and compare your tag against that

```
listRE="^($(printf '%s\n' "$list" | tr ' ' '|'))/"    # ^(feature|test|release)/
printf '%s\n' "$branch" | grep -E "$listRE"; echo "$?"
```

Comment: That would also give a false positive for `branch=$' anything really :-( \ntest/'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in a general case yes absolutely. But we're talking about tags and branches

Comment: Which is why it's important to reject values with newlines in them. We're talking of an input validation routine here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my evaluated from @Bodo one line version:

```
echo $list | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '^'"${branch%%/*}"'$'; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo  "VALID NAME"; else echo "NOPE"; exit 1; fi;
```

Comment: Note that this has the same problems as my grep-based solution if the value of branch contains any regex meta-characters, e.g. `branch='.*'`

Comment: See also `branch=$'test\n.\nanything really :-('`

Comment: sure, we have to  keep the naming convention for branch naming, but  I need a one-line solution.

Comment: @pulp_fiction, any script can be put on one line, but that generally doesn't help with legibility.

Comment: You're right, I do not intend to defend it, but for my use case, this solution fits.